# Do I need oAuth to retrieve public tweets with the new Twitter API guidelines? (and how?)

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, oauth

As I understand it, oAuth will soon be required for any call to the twitter API.

All I want to do is display a list of public tweets on a website using javascript. What would be best the way to do this considering twitters new guidelines on mandatory authentication? (I have never used the twitter API before)

Thank you.

Comment: where did you read that?

Comment: i don't have the link handy but it was on the twitter dev site where all the documentation and guidelines where, I believe there was an official blog post about it as well. They mentioned that the mandatory authentication would come into place in march to give people time to switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter will indeed soon require [some kind of authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api) for every API access:

> In version 1.1, **we will require every request to the API to be authenticated.**

For listing public tweets, you will probably only be required to [authenticate your application](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10175), so no user login will be required. However, there's no definite answer to this until Twitter releases their Twitter API Version 1.1 documentation.